# Salesforce Invalid conversion from runtime error - Map

Tags: apex, list, map

I'm making a callout to an external API via Apex and processing the response as such:

```
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(request);
    Map<String, Object> Response = (Map<String, Object>)System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
```

This compiles fine, but I get the following error at runtime:

> Invalid conversion from runtime type List to Map

The response body is in the following format (list size is always 1):

```
[
    {
        "licenceID": "543C",
        "status": "Current",
        "expiryDate": "17/11/2018",
    }
]
```

So I understand that it's detecting this as a list rather than a map but I'm not sure what the best way is to process this List. Essentially, I'd like to be able to get the value for licenceID, using something like this:

```
String licenceID = String.valueOf(Response.get('licenceId'));
```

Comment: try `List<Object> Response = (List<Object>)System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());`

Answer (score 0):

You can get `licenseId` value with following code.

```
 List<Object> Response = (List<Object>)System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
 Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)Response[0];
 System.debug(data.get('licenseId'));
```